# Improve performance of this combination algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, combinations, permutation

I'm working on [this kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/find-all-the-possible-numbers-multiple-of-3-with-the-digits-of-a-positive-integer/train/javascript) from Codewars. The task is:

> Given a certain number, how many multiples of three could you obtain with its digits?
>
> Supose that you have the number 362. The numbers that can be generated from it are:
>
> `362 ----> 3, 6, 2, 36, 63, 62, 26, 32, 23, 236, 263, 326, 362, 623, 632`

I've written the following recursive function to calculate all possiblities:

```js
const findMult_3 = (num) => {

  const powerset = (set) => {
    const combinations = []
    const combine = (prefix, chars) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        const newPrefix = parseInt(prefix + chars[i])
        if (!combinations.includes(newPrefix)) {
          combinations.push(newPrefix)
        } else {
          console.log('encountered duplicate')
        }
        combine(newPrefix, chars.filter((x, ind) => ind !== i))
      }
    }
    combine('', set)
    return combinations.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  }

  const allCombinations = powerset(num.toString().split(''))
  const factorsOfThree = allCombinations.filter(x => x % 3 === 0).filter(x => x !== 0)

  return [factorsOfThree.length, factorsOfThree.pop()]

}

findMult_3(43522283000229)
```

I noticed early on that I was encountered *a lot* of duplicate cases, hence the `console.log('encountered duplicate')` flag.

Execution of this algorithm is taking an extremely long time for large numbers, eg `43522283000229`.

How can I improve the performance of this code, or should it be scrapped entirely?

Comment: This would be better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most coding katas, the choice of algorithm is far more important that implementation details, but before we get to that, let me point out the most glaring flaw of your implementation:

```
    if (!combinations.includes(newPrefix)) {
      combinations.push(newPrefix)
    } else {
      console.log('encountered duplicate')
    }
    combine(newPrefix, chars.filter((x, ind) => ind !== i))
```

`combinations` is an array, and `includes` works by iterating over the array and checking every element. That is, to check whether an element is a duplicate, you are comparing it with every previously encountered combination. Since there are exponentially many of those, this is going to be very slow. If you used a dictionary object or `Map` instead, your code would be far faster.

Also, did you notice you are proceeding with generating combination even if the combination is a duplicate? That's redundant.

So the cheap improvement would be:

```
const combinations = {};
if (combinations[prefix]) {
  // duplicate, do nothing
} else {
  combinations[prefix] = true;
  combine(...);
}
```

The real improvement however is choosing a better algorithm. If you make use of the mathematical structure of the problem, you may be able to find the number of solutions without iterating over them all.

The following insights might help:

- a number is divisible by three if and only if the sum of its digits is.
- a sum of digits is divisible by 3 if and only if the sum of their remainders when divided by 3 is 0.
- the order of digits in the input does not matter

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had no idea the performance of `includes` is so terrible, as I've only used it with relatively small arrays. After changing to use a plain object instead, the performance is greatly improved. Your points about choosing a better algorithm from the start are duly noted as well.

Answer (score 0):

One (first) optimization would be to only check or generate numbers where the **sum of the digits is divisible by 3**, since only those numbers are divisible by 3.

So in your example (`362`) you could skip all combinations with `3 and 2`, `6 and 2` and all possible combinations with the 3 digits (because the sum of the 3 digits is not divisible by 3).

For the larger number (`43522283000229`) you can skip a lot more, for example all combinations with digits:

```
43, 35, 52, ...
435, 352, .., 283, ...
4352 (thus, including all possible combinations of those 4 digits), ...
43522, ...
43528, 43529, ...
43528309, ...
and so on
```

**Possible algorithm**:

```
Original number:        43522283000229

First, sort the digits: 00022222334589

Then find all distinct combinations of digits where
their sum is a multiple of 3:

left to right:

1 digit : 3, 9
2 digits: 03, 09, 24, 33, 39, 45, 48, ...
3 digits: 003, 009, 024, 033, 039, 222, 234, ...
n digits ...

Now, for all above numbers create every possible combination with their
digits, skip those with leading zeros.:

3, 9, 30, 90, 24, 42, 33, 39, 93, 45, 54, 48, 84, 300, 900,
204, 240, 402, 420, 309, 390, 903, 930, 222, 234, 243, ...

We don't have to check for division by 3, they all match.
We don't have to check for duplicates.

You could then sort the resulting list if needed.
```